# Half-dynamic multidimensional storage object

Tags: c++, memory-management, multidimensional-array, heap-memory

I am looking for a C++ multidimensional storage object that stores its data in a continuous memory block and is dynamic in one of its dimensions. Can you recommend me how to approach this?

Example:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 250>> pixelsMarker; 
// The array stores its data in a continuous block
// but the vector data not continuous, because
// an std::array is a complex object

std::vector<int[250]> pixelsMarker
// This is an invalid definition of a vector
```

Comment: Vector data is continuous always.

Comment: @amchacon I get that a vector is continuous, but storing an std::array stores the std::array class wrapper too, so the whole data is not going to be continuous.

Comment: The class wrapper for `std::array` is effectively nothing or `std::array<std::array<whatever>>` would not be contiguous.

Comment: You can verify that `std::array` isn't a "complex object" by testing `sizeof( std::array<int, 250> ) == sizeof(int[250])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation, using a `std::vector` as the underlying container type in a row-major configuration where the number of rows can be altered at run-time using `semi_dynamic_matrix::insert_row`, `semi_dynamic_matrix::erase_row`, `semi_dynamic_matrix::pop_row` and `semi_dynamic_matrix::rows_resize`.

```
template<typename Ty,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Ty>
> class semi_dynamic_matrix {
    class proxy_row_vector { // use to allow [][] usage on semi_dynamic_matrix objects
    public:
        proxy_row_vector(std::vector<Ty, Allocator>& _vec, std::size_t i, std::size_t cols) 
            : vec(_vec), row_ind(i), cols_(cols) {}
        const Ty& operator[](std::size_t j) const {
            return vec[row_ind*cols+j];
        }
        Ty& operator[](std::size_t j) {
            return vec[row_ind*cols+j];
        }
    private:
        std::vector<Ty, Allocator>& vec;
        std::size_t row_ind;
        std::size_t cols_;
    };
public:
    // PUBLIC TYPEDEFS
    typedef Ty value_type;
    typedef Ty& reference;
    typedef const Ty& const_reference;
    typedef Ty* pointer;
    typedef const Ty* const_pointer;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef Allocator allocator_type;
    typedef typename std::vector<Ty,Allocator>::iterator iterator;
    // and similar for const_iterator, reverse_iterator...
    // CONSTRUCTION/ASSIGNMENT
    // default constructor
    semi_dynamic_matrix() : semi_dynamic_matrix(Allocator()) {}
    explicit semi_dynamic_matrix(const Allocator& alloc)
        : mtx(alloc), rows_(0U), cols_(0U) {}
    // construct matrix of size rows*cols
    explicit semi_dynamic_matrix(size_type rows, size_type cols, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
        : mtx(rows*cols, alloc), rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {}
    // other constructors (copy, move, ...)
    // CAPACITY
    size_type rows() const noexcept { return rows_; }
    constexpr size_type columns() const noexcept { return cols_; }
    // ELEMENT ACCESS
    proxy_row_vector operator[](size_type i) const {
        return proxy_row_vector(mtx, i, cols_);
    }
    proxy_row_vector operator[](size_type i) {
        return proxy_row_vector(mtx, i, cols_);
    }
    // other accessors, e.g. at(), front(), ...
    // ITERATORS
    iterator begin() noexcept { return mtx.begin(); }
    iterator end() noexcept { return mtx.end(); }
    // similarly for cbegin(), cend(), rbegin(), ...
    // MODIFIERS
    iterator insert_row(size_type row_pos, const value_type& val) {
        return insert_row(row_pos, std::vector<value_type>(cols_, val));
    }
    iterator insert_row(size_type row_pos, const std::vector<value_type>& row_vec) {
        if (row_pos > rows_) throw std::out_of_range("message");
        if (row_vec.size() != cols_) throw std::invalid_argument("message");
        ++rows_;
        return mtx.insert(mtx.begin()+row_pos*cols_, row_vec.begin(), row_vec.end());
    }
    iterator insert_row(size_type row_pos, std::vector<value_type>&& row_vec =
        std::vector<value_type>()) {
        if (row_pos > rows_) throw std::out_of_range("message");
        if (row_vec.size() > cols_) throw std::invalid_argument("message");
        ++rows_;
        if (row_vec.size() < cols_) row_vec.resize(cols_);
        return mtx.insert(mtx.begin()+row_pos*cols_, std::make_move_iterator(
            row_vec.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(row_vec.end()));
    }
    iterator erase_row(size_type row_pos) {
        if (!(row_pos < rows_)) throw std::out_of_range("");
        --rows_;
        return mtx.erase(mtx.begin()+row_pos*cols_, mtx.begin()+cols_*(row_pos+1));
    }
    void pop_row() {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < cols_; ++i) mtx.pop_back();
        --rows_;
    }
    void rows_resize(size_type rows) {
        size_type tmp_rows = rows_;
        if (rows == rows_) return;
        if (rows > rows_) { // expand
            for (size_type i = 0; i < (rows_-tmp_rows); ++i)
                insert_row(rows_, std::move(std::vector<value_type>(cols_)));
        }
        else { // contract
            for (size_type i = 0; i < (tmp_rows-rows); ++i) pop_row();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<value_type, allocator_type> mtx;
    size_type rows_;
    size_type cols_;
};
```

Then you can use this like so,

```
semi_dynamic_matrix<int> sdm(3,3); // create matrix of size 3x3
sdm.rows_resize(5); // resize matrix to 5x3
sdm.erase_row(0); // erase first row of matrix, size is now 4x3
```

The underlying iterator type just uses the `std::vector` iterators so you can perform any of the typical `<algorithm>` header (and others) operations on this class.

Alternatively, if you want a matrix structure which is dynamic in both rows and columns then consider using an implementation I created a while ago: [`dynamic_matrix`](https://github.com/SJR276/crescent_library/blob/master/crescent_library/dynamic_matrix.h).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create your own accessor to the data and just use a single array?

For example:

```
std::vector<int> myArray(250*100);
```

Here you create 100 arrays with each of size of 250 (which is a single array with size 250*100). To access an element in array `N`, use a function

```
int accessor(int N, int elementNum)
{
    return N*250 + elementNum;
}
```

And this will give you the element `elementNum` in the `N`'th array.

Of course, you always have the option to inherit from `std::vector` or create your own class that will do this for you.

Comment: I cant, I'm using a bit-wise compression tool which I cannot modify and only works on continuous data blocks.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi What is not continuous in the solution I suggested?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Absolutely nothing, but seeing as OP's original `std::vector<std::array<int, 250>>`-based solution was also contiguous I still don't see the problem they are having. In fact the accepted solution  does exactly the same thing you did, but wraps it with an object instead of an accessor function.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a N-dimensional `std::array` a contiguous block, `std::array` must have no additional overhead. The only data that should be in `std::array` is the array. All data about the array is fixed by the template.

So if

```
std::array<std::array<int, 250>, 100> data;
```

is contiguous then

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 250>> data;
```

will also be contiguous.

That said, I can't find (or interpret) anything in a recent freely available draft of the standard (don't have an official copy) that guarantees that an implementation can't add in another member or two to just to ruin it for everybody, but why do such a thing?